# How to use the invoking element's text in an angular.js directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an angular.js directive to create a reusable custom button. It's my first directive so I've been pouring over the documentation, but most everything I've read assumes the directive code will operate on data from a controller model. But in this case I want to supply the button text as the element text, like so:

```
<div data-custom-button>Click Me</div>
```

The closest I've been able to come so far is adding a text attribute to the div. I've done this by setting the `scope.text` to '@' in the directive.

```
<div data-custom-button data-text="Click It">Click Me</div>
```

So the custom button html is working, but the button text is "Click It", but I want it to be "Click Me". The reason is that the app will support multiple interface languages via i18n, which populates the element text from the selected language file.

So this is how I'm invoking the directive:

```
<div data-custom-button data-text="Click It"
     data-i18n="common:controls.login">Click Me</div>
```

And the directive code in customButton.js:

```
app.directive("customButton", function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "customButton.html"
    };
});
```

And the customButton.html file:

```
<div class="customButtonWrapper">
    <!-- custom html removed for clarity -->
    <div class="customButtonText">{{text}}</div>
    <!-- custom html removed for clarity -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to refer to the invoking element's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where ng-transclude comes in handy

Change customButton.html to:

```
<div class="customButtonWrapper">
    <!-- custom html removed for clarity -->
    <div class="customButtonText" ng-transclude></div>
    <!-- custom html removed for clarity -->
</div>
```

And directive to:

```
app.directive("customButton", function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "customButton.html"
    };
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhxnqc0g/1/)

Comment: I accepted this answer because it does solve one of the major problems I was having. But there's a strange timing issue. It appears that the i18n code translates the button text and then the directive substitution occurs, but for some reason the resultant html has the *pre-translated* text. Very bizarre. Any idea what might be happening there?

Comment: Is your translation code running outside of the angular life-cycle. If so that the problem. Either use something like angular-translate or run the non-angular code within a module.run function. Although this assumes the code is synchronous, if the translation code is doing any form or AJAX calls to get the translated values you are SOL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use link function in the directive to achieve it. Basically the link function reads the text value from the div and assigns it to the isolated scope variable "text".

```
app.directive("customButton", function() {
return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          text: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: "customButton.html",
      link: function(scope,element,attr){
          $scope.text = element.text();
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I added a line to the link function `console.log(element.text())` and the value is "   {{text}}   ". Then I examined the element variable in the debugger and it appears to be the template / directive html element, not the invoking element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use transclude:

```js
app = angular.module('a',[]);
app.directive('customButton', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<button class="amazing">Yo! <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></button>',
    restrict: 'AE'
    
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="a">
<div custom-button="some">Super Text</div>
</body>
```